# How to set up a hotspot with socks5 proxy

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, proxy, socks

I have a laptop with linux installed on it. The laptop has two network interfaces: eth0 and wlan0. Normally I surf the Internet through eth0, and I've successfully set up a hotspot in linux for my kindle to use. Important codes are as follows:

```
# Enable NAT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# Run access point daemon
sudo hostapd /etc/ap-hotspot.conf
```

Usually I would like to surf the Internet through an encrypted socks5 proxy: 127.0.0.1:10000, and I want the proxy system-wide, so I installed redsocks, which can redirect all the TCP connections to the socks5 proxy. Important codes are as follows:

```
#redsocks requires all the data to be redirected to port 12345, and the socks5 address and port(127.0.0.1:10000) has been written to redsocks's configuration file.
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 12345
```

So far, It seems everything works great. My kindle can connect to the hotspot, and I can surf the Internet through a system-wide proxy in linux. The problem is, my kindle bypasses the socks5 proxy and connects to the Internet directly. So how to make my kindle go through the proxy when using the hotspot? I mean, how to do it in linux, because there's no way to set up a proxy in my kindle.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar set up. `wlan0` is connected to the internet (through my router) while `wlan1` acts as a hotspot (Access Point) for my Android phone. `wlan1` is set up with ipv4 address `10.0.0.1/24` that is my phone gets ip address in the `10.0.0.x` range.

The iptables rule I use to pass all traffic from my phone through redsocks is:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345`

As far as I understand it this rule basically takes all tcp traffic from any source device with address `10.0.0.0/24` and redirects it to the `12345` port which passes it through `redsocks`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had any experience with hostapd, but chances are that it modifies the routing table (and maybe even iptables).

after you start hostapd, it may be a good idea to run

netstat -nr

iptables -t nat -L

iptables -t filter -L

and try to work out where the packets are heading.

then, crank up your redsocks and have a new look at the full iptables setup

let me know those outputs, i may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

For me, redsocks worked with "socks5" proxy, for "http" proxy, i replaced it with "transocks", my iptables config looks like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Transocks: https://github.com/cybozu-go/transocks

set -e
stty -echoctl

# Point to the transparent socket port (running in an exclusive user)
TRANSOCKS_PORT=12345
TRANSOCKS_USER=transocks

# Redirect all the network of your computer (except transocks user)
REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK=1

# Redirect access point (wifi hotspot)
AP_SUBNET_ENABLED=1
AP_SUBNET_IFACE=ap0
AP_SUBNET_RANGE="192.168.12.0/24"

function action_up()
{
    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Adding iptables chain rules"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -t nat -N TRANSOCKS
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 198.18.0.0/15 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TRANSOCKS_PORT

    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting non-transocks user"
        echo "--------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "-----------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting AP subnet"
        echo "-----------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -I PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -I INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi
}

function action_down()
{
    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "------------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning non-transocks rules"
        echo "------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning AP subnet rules"
        echo "--------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -D INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi

    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Cleaning and removing chain"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -F TRANSOCKS -t nat
    iptables -v -X TRANSOCKS -t nat
}

trap 'action_down' SIGINT

action_up

echo
echo "Hit Ctrl+C to remove the ip table rules"
echo


while :
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question that was asked, it would be good to describe exactly how it solves the problem as well.